# Optimizing index update speed during bulk insert into table

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.1

When inserting large sets of data into a table (from another table, in no particular order), how do you optimize a multi-column index so that the index is updated in the fastest possible way?

Assume the index is never used in any `SELECT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE` query.* Assume also that the distinct counts for the columns as follows (for example):

```
COLUMN | DISTINCT COUNT
col1   |            634
col2   |          9,923
col3   |          2,357
col4   |              3
```

** Reason for not using the index in selecting data is this is a primary key index or a unique constraint index. The index is in place so that inserts violating the constraint should fail.*

I have read that the most selective column should come first. Is that correct, and is the index then to be created as follows?

```
(col2, col3, col1, col4)
```

If that is wrong, how do you determine the best order for column in an index which will only see bulk `INSERT`s into the corresponding table? The goal is to speed up the updating of the index during the bulk `INSERT`.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way is to `DROP INDEX`, then do the bulk inserts and `CREATE INDEX` when you are done inserting.

The proper structure of the index does not have so much to do with the distribution of values in the columns but with the retrieval strategies, presumably for `UPDATE` and `DELETE` only, and then specifically when you do partial filtering on some but not all always all columns of the index. Those more frequent filters should come first in your index columns. But you probably want to reconsider your indexing strategy more radically if this is the case: it may be better to have two or more indexes to match your typical retrieval strategies.

Ignoring your call for ignorance: why would you not apply the index to `SELECT` statements? Indexes are useful **only** for selecting subsets of data from your tables, whether that is for `SELECT` or a qualified `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. There is no functional difference for using indexes in any of these three operations.

Addendum after comments from OP: Indexes are useful for many purposes but their maintenance is relatively expensive, where "relatively" becomes "impossibly" very quickly with increasing table size. In your case you have to compare every record from your source table with every record in your destination table, or O(m*n) order. That is unworkable with tables of a large size, even with an index. Your best bet is to drop the index, do the inserts, create an index which is **not unique**, find and delete all duplicates, drop the index, finally create a new **unique index**.

Comment: Reason for not using in selecting data is this is a primary key index or a unique constraint index. The index is in place so that inserts violating the constraint should fail. Anyway thanks for the insights made. Is the speed of dropping and creating index faster than having the index update in-place? How is that so?

Comment: Also, now knowing that the index is a unique constraint, you may realize that dropping the index and creating it afterward is not a good idea as it defeats the purpose of the index. How can I optimize the speed of index update during the bulk insert while having the index in-place?

Comment: Thanks. That is not a very viable solution as I am expecting the entire bulk insert to fail (including the unique inserts) if there is a duplicate. But I understand your insights about the performance.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the columns is not terribly important for a uniqueness enforcement purposes.  But it would be unusual for a unique index to not also happen to be useful for some queries, and so I would order the columns to take advantage of that.

For bulk inserting into this index rapidly, I'd try inserting in index order.  So add an `order by (col2, col3, col1, col4)` to the select part of your insert.  This leads to more efficient IO.

Comment: *"This leads to more efficient IO."* Has this been verified?

Comment: Yep.  I do it all the time.  If the bulk load is too small compared to the table it is loaded into, you won't see much difference.  If the index has increased in size by several time since it was last rebuild, the improvement will be less than if it was recently rebuild (although this matters less than I thought it would)